# How to read how much numbers in text file?

Tags: python, file, text, count, numbers

**I don't know nothing about scripting** and this code was givin me from a forum that has nothing to do with this type of questions so i ask here to have a better feedback.

The "numbers.txt" contains a lot of numbers

```
10 20 30 40 50
1 2 3 4 5
11 12 13 14 15
3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
etc...
```

When i run the script and choose to see how much is there the number "1" it counts all the "1" include (10,11,12,13 etc...) and it's wrong is not what i need. How to correct this? Anyone could edit this code please, thanks.

```
def main():
    file  = open("numbers.txt", "r").read()
    value  = input("Enter the value: ")
    count = file.count(value)
 
    if count == 0:
        print("Invalid number.")
    else:
        print("Value occurrences: " + str(count))
main()
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve here, please be more specific. I would like to be helpful, but this site isn't really for people who don't know any code, it's for programmers with specific problems.

Comment: Are you trying to get a count of how many instances of a value there is, i.e how many 1's there are in the file, but counting only discrete "1"s, not the "1"s in "10", "11", etc?

Comment: Without know the exact format of the text file no one can give you an accurate answer. Your example has both comma and space separated values. Does your file have one, or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your numbers are all separated by whitespace (e.g. spaces, newlines, tabs) this will give you a count of each occurrence of whatever string you enter:

```
value  = input("Enter the value: ")

with open("numbers.txt", "r") as file_handler:

    text = file_handler.read()

    values = text.split()

    selects = [item for item in values if item == value ]

print("Value occurrences: ", str(len(selects)))
```

Comment: Imagine my file have 5 numbers (example) 10 11 12 13 14 if i ask if is there number 10 it will say yes, only "1" because any other number containing  just the "1" isn't "10". My file could have 1000 numbers, 500 wich of are number "50", so when i ask for that number it will say "500". I can separate the number by spaces, or anything else

Comment: This will work to do that, if your numbers are separated by spaces, tabs, or line breaks.

Comment: I'm getting this error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test\test2.py", line 9, in <module>
    selects = [item for item in list if item == value ]
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Comment: Updated and fixed a typo, try again.

Comment: One more little thing if is possible, after puting any number i must close and run the script to type again any other number... what is the code wich i can type as many as i want without closing/opening again the script. Thanks again man (just to not bump the thread),

Comment: As this is a whole different topic, it should be a new question. See a similar topic here which may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70512431/10245780